# Why does it says NA even there's data in it

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYCsx.png)

Why does it says NA?
This is a code that shows the diagonal elements.

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `mat4[u, v]` not `mat4[u][v]` (see below)
- instead of using nested loops to print the diagonal, you can use `diag(mat4)`

`some_matrix[u][v]` indexes first the u<sup>th</sup> element of `some_matrix` (walking row-by-row, column-by-column), returning an atomic vector of *length one*, of which it then tries to extract the v<sup>th</sup> element (which is NA for v > 1). `some_matrix[u, v]` instead indexes the matrix element in row u, column v.

*please don't provide data as image files but paste the output of `dput` (e.g.`dput(mat4)`)*